# syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) variable (T_VARIABLE) number (T_NUM_STRING) ...?

Tags: php, html, sql, select, sqlsrv

Mi código es como un filtro de búsqueda en el que hay que llenar campos para traer los datos,
Este es el formulario:

```
 <form action="Untitled-1.php" method="POST">
    
         Producto: &nbsp<input type="text" name="tipo_producto">
         Proyecto:  &nbsp<input type="text" name="nombre_proyecto"> 
         Marca: &nbsp<input type="text" name="marca"> 
         Modelo:  &nbsp<input type="text" name="modelo"> 
         Num. de parte: &nbsp<input type="text" name="parte">
        
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
        <input type="reset" value="Limpiar">
      </form>
```

aquí esta mi consulta

```
$sql=" SELECT 
       [CNOMBREPRODUCTO]
      ,[CNOMBREALMACEN] 
      ,[Movimientos].[CTEXTOEXTRA1] 
      ,[Movimientos].[CTEXTOEXTRA2] 
      ,[Movimientos].[CTEXTOEXTRA3] 
      FROM [Movimientos]
      INNER JOIN [Productos]
      on [Movimientos].[CIDPRODUCTO] = [Productos].[CIDPRODUCTO]
      INNER JOIN [Almacenes]
      on [Movimientos].[CIDALMACEN] = [Almacenes].[CIDALMACEN]

      WHERE $_POST['tipo_producto'] IS NULL OR [CNOMBREPRODUCTO] LIKE '".$_POST['tipo_producto']."'
      AND  $_POST['nomnre_proyecto']  IS NULL OR[CNOMBREALMACEN] LIKE '".$_POST['nombre_proyecto']."'
      AND  $_POST['marca']  IS NULL OR [Movimientos].[CTEXTOEXTRA1] LIKE '".$_POST['marca']."'
      AND  $_POST['modelo']  IS NULL OR [Movimientos].[CTEXTOEXTRA2] LIKE '".$_POST['modelo']."'
      AND  $_POST['parte']  IS NULL OR [Movimientos].[CTEXTOEXTRA3] LIKE '".$_POST['parte']."'";
```

No se si es mi sintaxis o que será, ya he tratado de cambiarla y me sale el mismo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando incluyes elementos de arreglos en una cadena encerrada entre comillas dobles, debes usar la [sintaxis compleja](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex), que no es realmente compleja, pero solo necesitas encerrar esos elementos entre llaves.

```
$sql=" SELECT 
       [CNOMBREPRODUCTO]
      ,[CNOMBREALMACEN] 
      ,[Movimientos].[CTEXTOEXTRA1] 
      ,[Movimientos].[CTEXTOEXTRA2] 
      ,[Movimientos].[CTEXTOEXTRA3] 
      FROM [Movimientos]
      INNER JOIN [Productos]
      on [Movimientos].[CIDPRODUCTO] = [Productos].[CIDPRODUCTO]
      INNER JOIN [Almacenes]
      on [Movimientos].[CIDALMACEN] = [Almacenes].[CIDALMACEN]

      WHERE {$_POST['tipo_producto']} IS NULL OR [CNOMBREPRODUCTO] LIKE '{$_POST['tipo_producto']}'
      AND  {$_POST['nomnre_proyecto']}  IS NULL OR[CNOMBREALMACEN] LIKE '{$_POST['nombre_proyecto']}'
      AND  {$_POST['marca']}  IS NULL OR [Movimientos].[CTEXTOEXTRA1] LIKE '{$_POST['marca']}'
      AND  {$_POST['modelo']}  IS NULL OR [Movimientos].[CTEXTOEXTRA2] LIKE '{$_POST['modelo']}'
      AND  {$_POST['parte']}  IS NULL OR [Movimientos].[CTEXTOEXTRA3] LIKE '{$_POST['parte']}'";
```

Esto va a solucionar solo el mensaje de error, pero creo que habrá errores en la consulta y, probablemente sea difícil que obtengas resultados adecuados. Por ejemplo:

```
campo LIKE 'texto'    -- Devuelve resultados igual que campo = 'texto'
campo LIKE 'texto%'   -- Devuelve resultados que inician con esa palabra
campo LIKE '%texto'   -- Devuelve resultados que terminan con esa palabra
campo LIKE '%texto%'  -- Devuelve resultados que contengan esa palabra
```

Aparte, te recomiendo leer [Cómo evitar inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php) para mejorar la seguridad de tu proyecto.